# find a file based on date passed in parameter

Tags: date

I have a requirement to find a next day file based on date provided in the parameter.

For example, I have these files:

```
XYZ.ABC.M.20200615180200.batch
XYZ.ABC.M.20200616180200.batch
XYZ.ABC.M.20200617180200.batch
```

and if the date provided in the parameter is `20200614`, then it should return the file `XYZ.ABC.M.20200615180200.batch`; the date provided by the parameter value is in the format `2020-06-14`.

I tried something like `date +%Y%m%d -d  "(2020-06-24)+1 days"`, but it's taking today's date instead of `20200615`. Can someone share the complete command to find the file `XYZ.ABC.M.20200615180200.batch` if the input date is `2020-06-14`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close.  Remove the parens and it should work:

```bsh
$ date +%Y%m%d -d "(2020-06-24)+1 days"
20200702

$ date +%Y%m%d -d "2020-06-24 +1 days"
20200625
```

Or, more specifically

```bsh
dt=20200614; # or 2020-06-14, either way works

file=$(date +"XYZ.ABC.M.%Y%m%d180200.batch" -d "$dt + 1 days");
echo $file;

XYZ.ABC.M.20200615180200.batch
```

Comment: I want to run the whole command in a single line by passing the output through pipes from location something like cd #input_location# | dt=20200614 | file=$(date +"XYZ.ABC.M.%Y%m%d180200.batch" -d "$dt + 1 days") | echo $file ;